# Dateformat suddenly different Javascript

Tags: javascript, datepicker

My date format is suddenly different in my forms here. I need to have it like yy-mm-dd. The second one is okay, but the first one suddenly changes. Can anybody see why?
Nice day to all of you from Julie

```
    <script>
  $(function() {
    $(".datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
  </head>
<body>

    DatePicker Ajax Post Example:

    <form method="post" id="myForm" action="getHoursSQL">
    Start Date:
        <input type="text" name="startDate" class="datepicker"/><br/>                     
    End Date:
        <input type="text" name="endDate" class="datepicker"/><br/>

        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
    <div id="startresult"></div>
    <div id="endresult"></div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("input[name=endDate]").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function(date, instance){            
             var jsonStr = $('#myForm').serializeArray();
            console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonStr));
              $.ajax({
                  url: "../getHoursSQL",
                  type: "post",
                  data: JSON,
                  success: function(data){
                      start: $("#startDate").val();
                      alert("success");
                      $("#startresult").html(data);

                  },
                  error:function(){
                      alert("failure");
                      $("#startresult").html('there is error while submit');
                  }  
                });
        }
    });
</script>
</html>
```

I am [image: Dateformat]

Comment: Code here doesn't look right `start: $("#startDate").val(); ...`

Comment: stupid question of me, but why not? :-)

Comment: there is no element with id#startDate there

Comment: Try putting your code here http://www.jshint.com/, it will tell you about errors. -- "Label 'start' on $ statement." -- Did you really mean to use a label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the your below script with below one

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $(".datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
```

With this one

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $(".datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
  });
  </script>
```

**Updated Answer**

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

 <script>
  $(function() {
    $(".datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
  });
  </script>
  </head>
<body>

    DatePicker Ajax Post Example:

    <form method="post" id="myForm" action="getHoursSQL">
    Start Date:
        <input type="text" name="startDate" class="datepicker"/><br/>                     
    End Date:
        <input type="text" name="endDate" class="datepicker"/><br/>

        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
    <div id="startresult"></div>
    <div id="endresult"></div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("input[name=endDate]").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function(date, instance){            
             var jsonStr = $('#myForm').serializeArray();

              $.ajax({
                  url: "../getHoursSQL",
                  type: "post",
                  data: JSON,
                  success: function(data){
                      start: $("#startDate").val();
                      alert("success");
                      $("#startresult").html(data);

                  },
                  error:function(){
                      alert("failure");
                      $("#startresult").html('there is error while submit');
                  }  
                });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. When I try this I can only pick a date in endDate. When I press startDate nothing happens :-/

Comment: @Julie24 actuly what action you need when clicking in Start date

Comment: the startDate and endDate is taking the input name from the form. The date is picking up through my servlet to the database: http://postimg.org/image/jav6sg1ol/
and returns me hours there has been worked in this period.

Answer (score 1):

You're only specifying the format for the `endDate` input when initialising its datepicker separately, all other `.datepicker` elements are initialised with the default options (you just call `.datepicker()` without passing an options object to it).

The default date format for the jQuery UI Datepicker is `mm/dd/yy`, as mentioned in [the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat). If you want the `yy-mm-dd` date format for *all* datepickers then you'll need to explicitly specify it when initialising them:

```
$(function() {
    $(".datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. When I try this I can only pick a date in endDate. When I press startDate nothing happens :-/

Comment: @Julie24 I missed a single quote on the end of the `dateFormat` value, fixed now in the answer. Appears to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/VfvWc/

Comment: argh shout. there was two <script> and <script> thanks a lot :-)